# Tile-Design with Relative-Layout different matching sizes / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

[Layout-Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITjqw.png)

Dear community,

I'm trying to design the Layout you can see on the link above with Android Studio but it seems to get too complicated for me. I used a couple of different layouts but I am not sure what layouts fits the best.

In detail:

-- 4 big buttons ( learning, vocabulary stack, add new.. )
-- automatic scaling on different android devices

I think the RelativeLayout is the best solution so I tried to..

..put the learning_Button and vocabulary_stack_Button on top, but how do I set the buttons to scaling tiles which both share 50% width from match_parent and have got 50% of heights from match_parent ?

.. how do I set the position of the Button add_new_vocabs_to_stack from 50% up to 80% of the height from match_parent ? I know that I will reach the full width for this button with normally match_parent

Please give me a good advise or point me to a good tutorial

Thanks in advance :-)